# parsing error in json

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

While I was running my application the following error appeared,and a blank page is displayed in ADV.
Here is a problem that I faced while parsing the inputs:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

I will be grateful if I can get some help.

### Class ListQuest.java

```
           public class ListQuest extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questsList = 
         new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

              // url to get all products list
                 private static String url_all_quests = 
                      "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/listquest.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_QUEST = "Question";
private static final String TAG_REP = "Reponse";
private static final String TAG_IDE = "idenq";
private static final String TAG_IDQ = "idquest";
private static final String TAG_LIBQ = "libquest";
private static final String TAG_LIBR = "librep";


// products JSONArray

String idenq;
String idquest;
String libquest,librep;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_quest);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    idenq = i.getStringExtra(TAG_IDE);
    idquest = i.getStringExtra(TAG_IDQ);


    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    questsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
    String idquest = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idquest)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    test.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_IDQ, idquest);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListQuest.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idenq", idenq));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idquest", idquest));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("libquest", libquest));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("librep", librep));
        // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_quests, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {




                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                JSONArray  Question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUEST);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < Question.length(); i++) {


                    // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    JSONObject c=Question.getJSONObject(i);
                    String libquest = c.getString(TAG_LIBQ);
                    JSONArray Reponse =c.getJSONArray(TAG_REP);


                    map.put(TAG_LIBQ, libquest);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList

                    // looping through All Products

                    for (int k =0 ; k < Reponse.length(); k++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new
                        HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject r=Reponse.getJSONObject(k);
                String librep = r.getString(TAG_LIBR);
                        map.put(TAG_LIBR, librep);

                    }
                    questsList.add(map);
                }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**     
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListQuest.this, questsList,
                        R.layout.list_quest, new String[] { 
                                TAG_LIBQ,TAG_LIBR},
                        new int[] {  R.id.libquest ,
                                         R.id.librep});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);



            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

### Class JsonParser

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and the result is:

```
        {"Question":[{"idquest":"17","libquest":"avez vous visité 
                       tunis?","Reponse":[{"librep":"oui"},{"librep":"non"}]},
             {"idquest":"50","libquest":"quel est votre       spécialité","Reponse":  
              [{"librep":"MP"},{"librep":"PC"}]},{"idquest":"51","libquest":"quel est 
                       votre équipe préféré","Reponse":[]}]}
```

Comment: find line throwing the exception in logcat and post that line along with your expected JSON format returned from "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/listquest.php"

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.                                      the class listquest.php:

Comment: Just some comment about proper Java programming: your *JSONParser* is actually a helper function/class to fetch some JSON data from a remote location with a method that should be static. Also your static class properties should probably be local variables in your method.

Comment: your string comparison `method == "POST"` does not work in Java. you have to use the `equals()` method.

Comment: @njzk2 I call you on that ;) aka: This is only partly true, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5 So, since the `method` argument is a string literal, it *does* work. You are however right in pointing this out since it can easily cause problems.

Comment: @dualed : i'll be damned. there is something seriously wrong with this language.

Comment: please help me I change my code but it only shows me the 2nd answer for each question. 
is what I can do two hash map one for questions and one for answers

Answer (score 1):

Mostly likely the string you are parsing is not what you think it is, and is actually not json. I would guess that its some sort of message starting with the word "You".

Comment: can you explain further please

Comment: My thought is that whatever source you are using for your JSON data is giving you something that is not JSON. For example, it could be sending you an error message. Whatever it is, when the parser tries to  make some sense out it it, it fails because the string of text is not valid JSON.

Comment: @user3597728 You did not add the real result of the request to your question, this result does not contain "You" anywhere. Use *exactly* the same arguments as in your Java program to get the result of `listquest.php`. Note that the "You" is very likely from an SQL error message (typically "You have an error in your SQL syntax") since your PHP script outputs SQL errors directly into the return message body with the `die` language construct. The resulting reply will not be valid JSON.

Comment: I modified the class ListQUest.java but when i raned my application 
the result of json  displayed  in logCat but in the ADV  i only get the second Reponse